# ruby chaining commands inline for a TCL programmer

Tags: ruby, tcl, chaining

I am a TCL programmer and do a lot of statement chaining and don't know how that can be done in ruby
For example if i would want to append the current time to the value of a variable

for example in tcl:

```
set mylist [list a b c,d,e f]
set myelem_with_time "[lindex [split [lindex $mylist 2] ,] 0][clock seconds]"

>>c{with some time value}
```

How can this be achieved in ruby without using separate lines for each command 
(of course its not an object class method or else use . operator, for example chaining the current time, or some arithmetic operation etc)

psudo code:

```
myval = mylist[2].split(",")[0] + time()+60seconds;
```

(I want to interpolate the time + 60 without calculating on a previous line)

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = %w[a b c,d,e f]

myelem_with_time = mylist[2].split(',')[0] + (Time.now + 60).to_i.to_s
# or
myelem_with_time = "%s%d" % [mylist[2].split(',')[0], (Time.now + 60).to_i]
# or
myelem_with_time = "#{mylist[2].split(',')[0]}#{(Time.now + 60).to_i}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your list from above and playing with your command:

```
mylist[2].split(",")[0] + (Time.now + 60).to_s
```

I got:

> e f2012-02-28 04:46:55 -0700

Is that what you're looking for (I did not strip the Date from the output but that is possible)

Comment: Tcl's `clock seconds` produces a count of seconds from the Unix epoch (e.g., `1330512568` for just now).